# Passing parameters to fragment declared in XML

Tags: android, android-fragments

I buld a simple application with ListFragment is structured like:

Fragments extends from ListFragment

- OneListFragment
- TwoListFragment

Activities extends from FragmentActivity

- MainActivity
- DetailActivity

The current logic is defined: in the MainActivity User clicks item from OneListFragment, start the DetailActivity, i need pass the extras from DetailActivity to the TwoListFragment but i dont know how?

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    final Cursor c = (Cursor) mAdapter.getItem(position);

    final Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(KEY, c.getString(0));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

#### `detail_activity.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/detailed_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        class="com.package.TwoListFragment" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use putExtra in your ListActivity and then, in TwoListFragment, use getActivity().getIntent().get***Extra()~